# Why do I get this OSError?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read a CSV file using pandas read_csv function but I keep getting an OSError. I have tried many different fixes but none of them seem to work. I have fixed a previous file not found error but unexpectedly got this error. Here is the code I used. Please note I am using Jupyter Notebook as part of Anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

curDir = os.getcwd()
#print(curDir)

melbourne_file_path = '..\Downloads\melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path) 
print(melbourne_data.describe())
```

This is the output/error I get:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-12283d886215> in <module>()
      6 
      7 melbourne_file_path = '..\Downloads\melb_data.csv'
----> 8 melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
      9 print(melbourne_data.describe())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, 
usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, 
true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, 
keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, 
infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, 
chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, 
quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, 
error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, 
delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, 
buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450  
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, 
engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = 
kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, 
engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, 
**kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers
```

Comment: Not the problem here, but a side-note: Always use raw strings (or forward slash delimited strings) for Windows paths. In this case, `'..\Downloads\melb_data.csv'` and `r'..\Downloads\melb_data.csv'` are the same, but if the file or folder names had started with `a`, `b`, `f`, `t`, `n`, `r`, sometimes `u`, `U` or `x`, and probably a couple others I'm forgetting, omitting the `r` prefix to make it a raw string would silently produce an invalid path thanks to the backslash being interpreted as an escape.

Comment: Shouldn't there be another line (at least) following the traceback that gives more information about the `OSError`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but it says `OSError: Initializing from file failed` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
melbourne_file_path = '../Downloads/melb_data.csv'
```

or

```
melbourne_file_path = '..\\Downloads\\melb_data.csv'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have tried this but still get the error above and at the end `OSError: Initializing from file failed`.

Comment: @HD Try update your condo package version first. conda update --all

Comment: Just to confirm, I type that in the Anaconda Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

If using Spyder 3.7, make sure that `#!/usr/bin/env python3` appears on line 1. Sometimes, a `temp.py` file is created when the correct Anaconda environment is not activated. The `temp.py` file may not have included  `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. The following two images show two files. The first one is missing the content of line 1 and the second includes the fix.

[without fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAHWN.png)

[with fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N962D.png)

1) ensure the `conda` environment is activated using source activate

2) ensure `#!/usr/bin/env python3` appears on line 1 of new python file